# SQL com 2 de várias condições

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Estou com problema para fazer um Select que atenda a 2 ou 3 condições de várias selecionadas, por exemplo:
Condições:

```
- Cidade Tal (São Paulo)
- Nome Tal (João)
- Sexo (Masculino)
- Fumante (Não)
- Carro Próprio (Sim)
```

Quero que volte para mim todos que atendam DUAS ou TRÊS das condições, dependendo do momento quero que atenda a DUAS delas, e em outros momentos quero 3 delas, mas gostaria de uma solução que não seja fazer combinações de OR e AND...

outra forma que não seja: `((Cidade AND Nome) OR (Cidade AND Sexo) OR (Cidade AND Fumante) OR (Cidade AND Carro) OR (Nome AND Sexo) OR (Nome AND Fumante) OR (Nome AND Carro) OR (Sexo AND Fumante) OR (Sexo AND Carro) OR (Fumante AND Carro))`

E a coisa fica pior ainda com mais opções e quando quero 3 quesitos em vez de 2....

```
------------ Tabela do Banco ------------
ID Nome  Estado Sexo Fuma Transporte Idade
1  Joao  RJ     Masc Sim  Sim        35
2  Maria SC     Fem  Sim  Sim        27
3  Jose  RJ     Masc Nao  Sim        23
4  Ana   SP     Fem  Nao  Nao        19
5  Carla SP     Fem  Nao  Sim        26
6  Bia   RJ     Fem  Nao  Nao        39
7  Edu   RJ     Masc Sim  Nao        18
8  Fabio SC     Masc Nao  Sim        31
...
```

Gostaria de um resultado que me traga somente quem atende a 3 das especificação:
`Estado: RJ Sexo: Feminino Fuma: Nao Transporte: Sim Idade: >30`

```
------------ Tabela Resultado ------------
ID Nome  Estado Sexo Fuma Transporte Idade
1  Joao  RJ     Masc Sim  Sim        35 (Estado: RJ & Transporte: Sim & idade >30)
3  Jose  RJ     Masc Nao  Sim        23 (Estado: RJ & Fuma: Nao & Transporte: Sim)
5  Carla SP     Fem  Nao  Sim        26 (Sexo: Fem & Fuma: Nao & Transporte: Sim)
6  Bia   RJ     Fem  Nao  Nao        39 (Estado: RJ & Sexo: Fem & Fuma: Nao & Idade >30 "essa atende a 4 dos requisitos")
8  Fabio SC     Masc Nao  Sim        31 (Fuma: Nao & Transporte: Sim & Idade >30)
...
```

Alguma luz no final do túnel?

Comment: Acredito que uma consulta contando os registros em uma tabela temporária deve resolver o seu problema. No momento estou sem tempo para descrever em detalhes uma resposta. Assim que puder formulo uma consulta com o resultado possível.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma tabela temporária e ir contando quantos registros atendem a cada condição.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `tmp_condicao`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_condicao(
  id INT NOT NULL primary key,
  qtd INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tmp_condicao(id, qtd)
SELECT
  id,
  0
FROM minhaTabela;

UPDATE tmp_condicao AS A
INNER JOIN minhaTabela AS B
  ON (A.id = B.id)
SET A.qtd = A.qtd + 1
WHERE B.estado = 'RJ';

SELECT
*
FROM tmp_condicao;
```

Para cada nova condição que você tiver, basta repetir o `UPDATE` e adicionar o `WHERE` que você quer adicionar.

Por fim, para buscar os registros que tem 3 condições ou mais você pode fazer:

```
SELECT
B.*
FROM tmp_condicao AS A
INNER JOIN minhaTabela AS B
  ON (A.id = B.id)
WHERE A.qtd >= 3;
```

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Bem, você pode concatenar sua query.

exemplo:

```
$query = "SELECT * from table WHERE 1 = 1";
if ($nome)
{
    $query .= "Nome = ". $nome;
}
if ($cidade)
{
    $query .= "Cidade = ". $cidade;
}
```

Isso é só um exemplo. Sugiro usar PDO por motivos de segurança. :)